# How to modify close button in submenu of jQuery mobile for initial opening

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have a main menu and a click on a button of the main menu opens a sub menu with either long or short list items. Selecting one or more items changes the grey close button in the left upper corner to a green check mark. If all items get unselected the green check mark turns into an orange close button.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">       
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>


    <script> 

    <!-- beginning dialog submenu -->

    $(document).on("selectmenucreate", "#country-select", function(e, ui) {
      var data = $(this).data("mobile-selectmenu"), hide = {"display": "none"};
      data.list
        .attr("data-filter", "true")
        .find("li[data-placeholder='true']").css(hide);
      $(this).on("change", function () {
        var cases = {"page": data.menuPageClose, "overlay": data.headerClose},
            btnClose = cases[data.menuType];
        if ($("option:selected", this).length === 0) {
          btnClose
            .addClass("ui-icon-delete")
            .removeClass("ui-icon-check")
            .css("backgroundColor", "orange")
            .css("width", 55)
            .css("height", 32)
            .css("border", "red solid 1px");
        } else {
          btnClose
            .addClass("ui-icon-check")
            .removeClass("ui-icon-delete")
            .css("backgroundColor", "#90ee90")
            .css("width", 55)
            .css("height", 32)
            .css("border", "green solid 1px");
        }
      });
    });

    $(document).on("pagecontainerbeforeshow", function(e, ui) {
      var data = $("#country-select").data("mobile-selectmenu");
      if(ui.toPage.attr("id") == data["dialogId"]) {
        if(!ui.toPage.find(".ui-filterable").length) {
          ui.toPage.find(".ui-content").enhanceWithin();
        }
      }
    });

    $(document).on("pagecontainershow", function(e, ui) {
      var data = $("#country-select").data("mobile-selectmenu");
      if(ui.toPage.attr("id") == data["dialogId"]) {
        ui.toPage.find(".ui-filterable input").focus();
      }
    });

    $(document).on("pagecontainerhide", function(e, ui) {
      var data = $("#country-select").data("mobile-selectmenu");
      if(ui.prevPage.attr("id") == data["dialogId"]) {
        data["list"].find("li").removeClass("ui-screen-hidden");
        ui.prevPage.find(".ui-filterable input").val("");
      }
    });                                                                   

    <!-- end dialog submenu -->



    <!-- beginning popup submenu -->

    $(document).on("selectmenucreate", "#city-select", function(e, ui) {
      var data = $(this).data("mobile-selectmenu"), hide = {"display": "none"};
      data.list.attr("data-filter", "true").find("li[data-placeholder='true']").css(hide); 
      $("#" + data.popupId).enhanceWithin().popup("option", {positionTo: "window"});
      $("#" + data.menuId).css("max-height", "0");
      $(this).on("change", function () {
        var cases = {"page": data.menuPageClose, "overlay": data.headerClose},
            btnClose = cases[data.menuType];
        if ($("option:selected", this).length === 0) {
          btnClose
             .addClass("ui-icon-delete")
             .removeClass("ui-icon-check")
             .css("backgroundColor", "orange")
             .css("width", 55)
             .css("height", 32)
             .css("border", "red solid 1px");      
        } else {
          btnClose
            .addClass("ui-icon-check")
            .removeClass("ui-icon-delete")
            .css("backgroundColor", "#90ee90")
            .css("width", 55)
            .css("height", 32)
            .css("border", "green solid 1px");
        }
      }); 
    });

    $(document).on("popupbeforeposition", function(e, ui) {
      var data = $("#city-select").data("mobile-selectmenu");
      if(e.target.id == data.popupId) {
        var popup = $("#" + data.popupId), sH = $.mobile.getScreenHeight(),
            pH = popup.height(), oH = popup.outerHeight(true),
            hH = popup.find(".ui-header").outerHeight(true),
            fH = popup.find(".ui-filterable").outerHeight(true),
            iH = popup.find("li").outerHeight(true),
            maxItems = ((sH - oH + pH - hH - fH - 50) / iH)|0, maxHeight = maxItems * iH;
        $("#" + data.menuId).css("max-height", maxHeight+"px");
        popup.find(".ui-filterable input").focus();
      }
    });

    $(document).on("popupafterclose", function(e, ui) {
      var data = $("#city-select").data("mobile-selectmenu");
      if(e.target.id == data.popupId) {
        data.list.find("li").removeClass("ui-screen-hidden");
        $(e.target).find(".ui-filterable input").val("");
        $("#" + data.menuId).css("max-height", "0");
      }
    });

    $(document).on("popupafteropen", function(e, ui) {
      if(e.target.id == $("#city-select").data("mobile-selectmenu").popupId) {
        $(e.target).find(".ui-filterable input").focus();
      }
    });

    <!-- end popup submenu -->

    </script>


    <style>

    .ui-selectmenu.ui-popup .ui-input-search {
        margin-left: .5em;
        margin-right: .5em;
    }

    .ui-selectmenu.ui-dialog .ui-content {
        padding-top: 0;
        max-height: 85vh;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .ui-selectmenu.ui-dialog .ui-selectmenu-list {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    .ui-selectmenu.ui-popup .ui-selectmenu-list li.ui-first-child .ui-btn {
        border-top-width: 1px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0;
        border-radius: 0;

    }
    .ui-selectmenu.ui-popup .ui-header {
        border-bottom-width: 1px;
        padding-left: 40px;
    }

    .ui-selectmenu.ui-dialog .ui-header {
        border-bottom-width: 1px;
        padding-left: 40px;
    }

    /* scrollable listview for select popup */
    .ui-selectmenu-list.ui-listview {
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
    /* just some air around the popup */
    .ui-selectmenu.ui-popup {
      padding: 0.6em;
    }                             

    </style>

    </head>

    <body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="content">

          <div class="ui-field-contain">

            <label for="country-select">Select Country</label>
            <select name="country-select" id="country-select" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">

                <option>Choose Your Country</option>
                <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                <option value="CA">California</option>
                <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                <option value="NY">New York</option>
                <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>

            </select>
         </div>


         <div class="ui-field-contain">

            <label for="country-select">Select City</label>
            <select name="city-select" id="city-select" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">

                <option>Choose Your City</option>
                <option value="LA">Los Angeles</option>
                <option value="NY">New York</option>
                <option value="SF">San Francisco</option>
                <option value="WH">Washington</option>

            </select>

         </div>


        </div>
    </div><!-- /page -->
```

Now, I want the orange close button to appear not only after unselecting all options but as default setting when the submenu is opened for the first time in dialog and popup submenues.

Thanks!

Comment: I just realized that You have more than one custom-select inside Your page... So, just for the posterity, I fixed my implementation in Your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60419526/how-to-fix-search-field-below-header-in-submenu-of-jquery-mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change default style to orange button by add following css.

```
#city-select-listbox .ui-icon-delete,
#country-select-dialog .ui-icon-delete {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 55px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```css
#city-select-listbox .ui-icon-delete,
#country-select-dialog .ui-icon-delete {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 55px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>


<script>
  <!-- beginning dialog submenu -->

  $(document).on("selectmenucreate", "#country-select", function(e, ui) {
    var data = $(this).data("mobile-selectmenu"),
      hide = {
        "display": "none"
      };
    data.list
      .attr("data-filter", "true")
      .find("li[data-placeholder='true']").css(hide);
    $(this).on("change", function() {
      var cases = {
          "page": data.menuPageClose,
          "overlay": data.headerClose
        },
        btnClose = cases[data.menuType];
      if ($("option:selected", this).length === 0) {
        btnClose
          .addClass("ui-icon-delete")
          .removeClass("ui-icon-check")
          .css("backgroundColor", "orange")
          .css("width", 55)
          .css("height", 32)
          .css("border", "red solid 1px");
      } else {
        btnClose
          .addClass("ui-icon-check")
          .removeClass("ui-icon-delete")
          .css("backgroundColor", "#90ee90")
          .css("width", 55)
          .css("height", 32)
          .css("border", "green solid 1px");
      }
    });
  });

  $(document).on("pagecontainerbeforeshow", function(e, ui) {
    var data = $("#country-select").data("mobile-selectmenu");
    if (ui.toPage.attr("id") == data["dialogId"]) {
      if (!ui.toPage.find(".ui-filterable").length) {
        ui.toPage.find(".ui-content").enhanceWithin();
      }
    }
  });

  $(document).on("pagecontainershow", function(e, ui) {
    var data = $("#country-select").data("mobile-selectmenu");
    if (ui.toPage.attr("id") == data["dialogId"]) {
      ui.toPage.find(".ui-filterable input").focus();
    }
  });

  $(document).on("pagecontainerhide", function(e, ui) {
    var data = $("#country-select").data("mobile-selectmenu");
    if (ui.prevPage.attr("id") == data["dialogId"]) {
      data["list"].find("li").removeClass("ui-screen-hidden");
      ui.prevPage.find(".ui-filterable input").val("");
    }
  });

  <!-- end dialog submenu -->



  <!-- beginning popup submenu -->

  $(document).on("selectmenucreate", "#city-select", function(e, ui) {
    var data = $(this).data("mobile-selectmenu"),
      hide = {
        "display": "none"
      };
    data.list.attr("data-filter", "true").find("li[data-placeholder='true']").css(hide);
    $("#" + data.popupId).enhanceWithin().popup("option", {
      positionTo: "window"
    });
    $("#" + data.menuId).css("max-height", "0");
    $(this).on("change", function() {
      var cases = {
          "page": data.menuPageClose,
          "overlay": data.headerClose
        },
        btnClose = cases[data.menuType];
      if ($("option:selected", this).length === 0) {
        btnClose
          .addClass("ui-icon-delete")
          .removeClass("ui-icon-check")
          .css("backgroundColor", "orange")
          .css("width", 55)
          .css("height", 32)
          .css("border", "red solid 1px");
      } else {
        btnClose
          .addClass("ui-icon-check")
          .removeClass("ui-icon-delete")
          .css("backgroundColor", "#90ee90")
          .css("width", 55)
          .css("height", 32)
          .css("border", "green solid 1px");
      }
    });
  });

  $(document).on("popupbeforeposition", function(e, ui) {
    var data = $("#city-select").data("mobile-selectmenu");
    if (e.target.id == data.popupId) {
      var popup = $("#" + data.popupId),
        sH = $.mobile.getScreenHeight(),
        pH = popup.height(),
        oH = popup.outerHeight(true),
        hH = popup.find(".ui-header").outerHeight(true),
        fH = popup.find(".ui-filterable").outerHeight(true),
        iH = popup.find("li").outerHeight(true),
        maxItems = ((sH - oH + pH - hH - fH - 50) / iH) | 0,
        maxHeight = maxItems * iH;
      $("#" + data.menuId).css("max-height", maxHeight + "px");
      popup.find(".ui-filterable input").focus();
    }
  });

  $(document).on("popupafterclose", function(e, ui) {
    var data = $("#city-select").data("mobile-selectmenu");
    if (e.target.id == data.popupId) {
      data.list.find("li").removeClass("ui-screen-hidden");
      $(e.target).find(".ui-filterable input").val("");
      $("#" + data.menuId).css("max-height", "0");
    }
  });

  $(document).on("popupafteropen", function(e, ui) {
    if (e.target.id == $("#city-select").data("mobile-selectmenu").popupId) {
      $(e.target).find(".ui-filterable input").focus();
    }
  });

  <!-- end popup submenu -->
</script>


<style>
  .ui-selectmenu.ui-popup .ui-input-search {
    margin-left: .5em;
    margin-right: .5em;
  }
  
  .ui-selectmenu.ui-dialog .ui-content {
    padding-top: 0;
    max-height: 85vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
  
  .ui-selectmenu.ui-dialog .ui-selectmenu-list {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  
  .ui-selectmenu.ui-popup .ui-selectmenu-list li.ui-first-child .ui-btn {
    border-top-width: 1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  
  .ui-selectmenu.ui-popup .ui-header {
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    padding-left: 40px;
  }
  
  .ui-selectmenu.ui-dialog .ui-header {
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    padding-left: 40px;
  }
  /* scrollable listview for select popup */
  
  .ui-selectmenu-list.ui-listview {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
  /* just some air around the popup */
  
  .ui-selectmenu.ui-popup {
    padding: 0.6em;
  }
</style>

</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">

      <div class="ui-field-contain">

        <label for="country-select">Select Country</label>
        <select name="country-select" id="country-select" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">

          <option>Choose Your Country</option>
          <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
          <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
          <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
          <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
          <option value="CA">California</option>
          <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
          <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
          <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
          <option value="FL">Florida</option>
          <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
          <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
          <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
          <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
          <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
          <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
          <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
          <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
          <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
          <option value="ME">Maine</option>
          <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
          <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
          <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
          <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
          <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
          <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
          <option value="MT">Montana</option>
          <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
          <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
          <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
          <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
          <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
          <option value="NY">New York</option>
          <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
          <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
          <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
          <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
          <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
          <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
          <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
          <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
          <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
          <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
          <option value="TX">Texas</option>
          <option value="UT">Utah</option>
          <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
          <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
          <option value="WA">Washington</option>
          <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
          <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
          <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>

        </select>
      </div>


      <div class="ui-field-contain">

        <label for="country-select">Select City</label>
        <select name="city-select" id="city-select" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">

          <option>Choose Your City</option>
          <option value="LA">Los Angeles</option>
          <option value="NY">New York</option>
          <option value="SF">San Francisco</option>
          <option value="WH">Washington</option>

        </select>

      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /page -->
```